# Not enough disk space available or Next button greyed out

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install ubuntu desktop 23.04 on my computer and to erase windows 10. I use UEFI boot. I have already installed ubuntu dual-boot on this computer but now i have only windows installed. When i boot on the usb drive and go through the installation process in ubuntu, i get the following message : "not enough disk space available, 0 B available, 0 B required" or just the next button greyed out at the step "erase disk and install ubuntu" or "manual partitioning". I have tried flashing my usb drive with Rufus or balena etcher. I cannot find any solution on the internet. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: 23.04 is going out of support in **three months**. Instead try to install 23.10 or 22.04.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have all the disk space occupied by Windows and the previous ubuntu installation partitions.

Depending on what you want to do next, you can either:

- erase everything and install ubuntu on the whole disk,
- format the partition where ubuntu was previously installed (I'm
  assuming it's a single partition and its file system is ext4), set a
  mount point of "/" on it, and select the swap partition.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. No, there is one partition for Windows (C:) and the rest of the disk space is free. I have no swap partition, I thought that the option "erase disk and install Ubuntu" was supposed to do all the work for me. I'll try the second option then.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a bootable device with the desired version of Ubuntu, running it "live" and selecting erase disk and install Ubuntu should indeed work fine.  However understand that this option will remove Windows and anything else from the medium.  You will be warned of this several times during the install process.

If you want to keep Windows and make the system dual boot there is a choice in the installation process to do this.  The previous answer highlights the overview on how to do this.

Creating a dual boot Ubuntu installation and various problems encountered when doing so are well documented on this site.

[Ubuntu wrongly warns "Not enough space" despite actually having enough space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103590/ubuntu-wrongly-warns-not-enough-space-despite-actually-having-enough-space?rq=1)